# How do I sequentially get the index and column of the highest, next highest, etc. number in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame of the general form (let's call it `df`)

```
    A       C       D       E       F
0   0.4     0.1     0.2     0       0.7
1   0       0.2     0       0.5     0.6
2   0.1     0.5     0       0       0
3   0       0       0       0.8     0
4   0.8     0.1     0       0       0
5   0       0.9     0       0       0
```

Though each axis will be longer (21 columns, varying index length).

I need to find the largest number in the entire DataFrame, and extract the index and column name, then the next largest (if not in same index) and again find index and column name, and so on.

I can of course extract each index as a series (`pd.Index.to_series`) or list, and do it item-wise. But I'm thinking there's a more efficient way using the dataframes (since I cannot predict the maximum index size this will eventually be used on), that I just can't seem to find/think of.

I've found plenty of answer using `df.max()` or `df.idmax()`, to get the maximum, if I only needed that.

Comment: So basically you want to sort the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following:

```
df.stack().reset_index().sort_values(by=0, ascending=False)
Out[168]: 
    level_0 level_1    0
26        5       C  0.9
18        3       E  0.8
20        4       A  0.8
4         0       F  0.7
9         1       F  0.6
8         1       E  0.5
11        2       C  0.5
0         0       A  0.4
6         1       C  0.2
2         0       D  0.2
10        2       A  0.1
1         0       C  0.1
21        4       C  0.1
27        5       D  0.0
28        5       E  0.0
25        5       A  0.0
24        4       F  0.0
23        4       E  0.0
22        4       D  0.0
15        3       A  0.0
19        3       F  0.0
17        3       D  0.0
16        3       C  0.0
14        2       F  0.0
13        2       E  0.0
12        2       D  0.0
7         1       D  0.0
5         1       A  0.0
3         0       E  0.0
29        5       F  0.0
```

Comment: Thanks, really nice! How would one "index" the first now? I create an empty dataframe (`df2`), and append this output, and then access using the "new" index (e.g. `df2._get_value(0, 'level_1')`); is there a way to directly index the first, second (etc.) row of the output?

Comment: Sure, you would do df.iloc[0] to access the first item in the dataframe, df.iloc[1] for the second item... etc

Comment: Oops, I guess I should have though that one through - used iloc a few hours before posting the original question. Well, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
print(
    df.reset_index()
    .melt("index")
    .sort_values(by="value", ascending=False)[["index", "variable"]]
)
```

Prints:

```
    index variable
11      5        C
21      3        E
4       4        A
24      0        F
25      1        F
8       2        C
19      1        E
0       0        A
7       1        C
12      0        D
2       2        A
6       0        C
10      4        C
23      5        E
22      4        E
26      2        F
27      3        F
28      4        F
20      2        E
15      3        D
18      0        E
17      5        D
16      4        D
1       1        A
14      2        D
13      1        D
9       3        C
5       5        A
3       3        A
29      5        F
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! I accepted the other answer since they both do what I asked, but I like (though I hadn't though about that before) that it retains the values.

Comment: @Aephir To retain values just remove the `[["index", "variable"]]` at the end.